# How can I Make a Successful Domain Object Factory in PHP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, domain-object

I'm fiddling with an MVC framework, and I stumbled upon a problem I'm not sure how to solve.

I want to make a `DomainObjectFactory` for the Model layer of my application, however, each Domain object would have a different set of arguments, for instance:

- Person - $id, $name, $age.
- Post - $id, $author, $title, $content, $comments
- Comment - $id, $author, $content

And so on. How can I easily tell my factory what kinds of object do I require?

I've came up with several options:

- Pass an array - I dislike this one, because you can't rely on the constructor's contract to tell what the object needs for his work.
- Make the `DomainObjectFactory` an interface, and make concrete classes - Problematic, because that's an awful lot of factories to make!
- Use Reflection - Service locator much? I don't know, it just seems that way to me.

Is there a useful deign pattern I can employ here? Or some other clever solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to initialize a [*Domain Object*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) with all the properties assigned?

Instead just create an empty *Domain Object*. You might in the factory check, if it has `prepare()` method to execute. Oh .. and if you are using [*DAO*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html), instead of directly interacting with [*Mappers*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), you might want to construct and inject the appropriate *DAO* in your *Domain Object*.

The assignment of values should just happen in the [*Service*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29). By the use of ordinary setters.

#### Some examples:

> <sub>Retrieving existing article</sub>

```
public function retrieveArticle( $id )
{
    $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->create('Article');
    $article = $this->domainFactory->create('Article');
    
    $article->setId( $id );
    $mapper->fetch( $article );
    $this->currentArticle = $article;
}
```

> <sub>Posting new comment</sub>

```
public function addComment( $id, $content )
{

    $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->create('article');
    $article = $this->domainFactory->create('Article');
    $comment = $this->domainFactory->create('Comment');

    $comment->setContent( $content );
    $comment->setAuthor( /* user object that you retrieved from Recognition service */ );

    $article->setId( $id );
    $article->addComment( $comment );
    // or you might retrieve the ID of currently view article
    // and assign it .. depends how you build it all
    
    $mapper->store( $article ); // or 
}
```

> <sub>Passing user input</sub>

```
public function getArticle( $request )
{
    $library = $this->serviceFactory->build('Library');
    $library->retrieveArticle( $request->getParameter('articleId'));
}
```

Comment: So you're saying I should generate empty Domain Objects, and let my Data Mappers alone fill them? How do I deal with user input?

Comment: When factory releases the DO, it is empty. You assign some conditions to it, and then fetch the values .. or store them.

Comment: But then, how would you deal with user input? Making a DM of its own doesn't sound right

Comment: I am not sure this is correct, but my [Front Controller](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) captures user input (usually from the POST array, but it could be from other input), and creates a Request object that contains the data entered by the user, which is then passed into the appropriate controller (based on the requested action).

Comment: @tereško in code examples, you used [create] method for mapper/domain factories and [build] method for service factory. Was this on purpose (service 'build' does something different?) or just different name for the same thing?

Comment: @Andrew honestly, no idea. I probably lost my train-of-thought at some point and forgot which name I was using. Then again, the name of the method that you use for supplying instances doesn't matter,